# Why is the class of instance of generic type not the same as the generic type class?

Tags: generics, java-8, generic-type-argument

EDIT: even more simple example:

```
public <T> void shouldBeAbleToGetClassOfT(T t) {
    Class<T> tClass;

    // OK, but shows "unchecked cast" warrning.
    tClass = (Class<T>) t.getClass();

    // Compilation error!
    tClass = t.getClass();
}
```

> Incompatible types.
>
> Required: Class<T>
>
> Found: Class<capture<? extends java.lang.Object>>

I am a little confused about the type erasure in the example below:

```
public static class Example<T> {
    private final T t;

    public Example(final T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public <U extends T> void test(Consumer<T> consumer, U u) {
        // OK, but shows "unchecked cast" warrning.
        consumer.accept((T) t.getClass().cast(u));

        // OK, but shows "unchecked cast" warrning.
        consumer.accept(((Class<T>)t.getClass()).cast(u));

        // Compilation error!
        consumer.accept(t.getClass().cast(u));
    }
}
```

The error in question is:

> Error:(21, 46) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T

What exactly is happening here?

Is the `.getClass()` return value erased? Why?

What is the best way to handle this error?

---

**EDIT**: here is a little more complex use case, more closely related to my problem:

```
public class A<T> {
    private final T t;

    public A(final T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void printClass() {
        // OK, but shows "unchecked cast" warrning.
        B<T> b = new B<>((Class<T>) t.getClass());

        // Compilation error!
        B<T> b = new B<T>(t.getClass());

        b.printClass();
    }
}

public class B<T> {
    private final Class<T> t;

    public B(final Class<T> t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void printClass() {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the explicit cast? `U u` is already a `T` from your compiler's point of view, because `U extends T`, so a `Consumer<T>` should accept an `U` any time! Just remove the cast and be happy, or if it's something else you're struggling with, describe your original problem instead.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete for clarification, I've added a little more complex example, more closely related to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for [`getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--):

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

The static type of `t` is `T`, and the erasure of that is `Object`. That means that `t.getClass()` has static type `Class<? extends Object>`, not `Class<? extends T>` as you might expect.

Since `t.getClass()` has static type `Class<? extends Object>`, the compiler only knows that `t.getClass().cast(u)` is an `Object`, not a `T`. That means you can't pass it to `consumer.accept`.

Comment: I see. How would you deal with this problem though? `@SuppressWarnings`?

Comment: @Jezor: That would depend on your actual use case. Usually, you shouldn't even be in this situation; `Class.cast` is weird and rarely necessary. Both `Class.cast` and `U` are superfluous in your example.

Comment: Thing is, the actual use case is a lot more complex, so I wanted to post as minimal example as possible.

Comment: @Jezor: `Class.cast` is still probably unnecessary in your actual use case.

Comment: Yes, it is unnecessary. I've added a little more complex use case to my question, it's more closely related to the actual problem.

Comment: @Jezor: The new example isn't quite right, because if `t` is an instance of a subclass of `T`, then `t.getClass()` is a `Class<SomeSubclass>`, not a `Class<T>`. Still, if you correct that, I'd say this is a case for an unchecked cast and a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: You might also consider taking a `Class<T>` as an explicit argument, instead of calling `getClass` (and possibly getting a subclass).

Comment: @Jezor: Even for your “little more complex use case”, there is no reason to require `Class` to be parameterized by `T`, as printing it, i.e. invoking its `toString()` method, has no dependency to `T`.